# For which interval the function $f(x)=\sqrt[3]x(x-8)$ concave upward? (having issue with $x<0$)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For which interval the function $f(x)=\sqrt[3]x(x-8)$ concave upward?

$1) (-2,-1) \qquad\qquad 2)(-2,2)\qquad\qquad3)(-5,-2)\qquad\qquad4)(-6,-5)$

It happens when $f''(x)\ge0$:

$$f'(x)=\frac43 x^{\tfrac13}-\frac83x^{-\tfrac23}$$
$$f''(x)=\frac49x^{-\tfrac23}+\frac{16}9x^{-\tfrac53}=\frac49x^{-\tfrac53}(x+4)$$
And $f''(x)\ge0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}-[-4,0]$. so it seems the answer is fourth option.

But when I was checking my work with the [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Bx%7D%28x-8%29), I see it sketch the graph only for $x\ge0$. but why? Does the question posed badly or it is a problem with wolfram alpha?

Comment: Desmos plots the complete graph for all $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Wolframalpha has interpreted your latex command as the principal complex square root (which is in itself an outstanding fact, in my opinion). The proper mathematica command for the real square root would be Surd[x,3].